# Join GLPCA and GLPCT tables

Tags: abap, opensql, sap-r3

Im trying to join GLPCA and GLPCT but I dont know which fields to use.

I am not a SAP/ABAP user I just use the tables as data sources, all I know is that they belong to SAP R3.

Does anyone knows how to make a join between this tables?

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

I assume you should stick to GLPCT primary key while joining:

```
SELECT *
  INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE lt_join
  FROM glpca AS a
  JOIN glpct AS t
    ON a~rldnr = t~rldnr
   AND a~rrcty = t~rrcty
   AND a~rvers = t~rvers
   AND a~ryear = t~ryear
   AND a~trcur = t~rtcur
   AND a~runit = t~runit
   AND a~drcrk = t~drcrk
   AND a~poper = t~rpmax.
```

Pay attention to the business sense of GLPCA/GLPCT tables: while GLPCA simply  lists line items, GLPCT shows accumulated values. Check the note [180906](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/180906) for more information.